# URI prefix is not recognized when using WebSocket with Unity

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, websocket

```
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string uri = "ws://localhost:4567";
    private ClientWebSocket ws;

    void Start()
    {
        ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None).Wait();
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity version 2017.1.0b7 Personal.

I went to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Inspector -> Other Settings -> Configuration` and set `Scripting Runtime Version` to `Experimental (.NET 4.6 Equivalent)`. The `API Compatibility Level` has become `.NET 4.6`.
After that, the code above works perfectly well in a built-in Unity player in the IDE. It does connect to my localhost-ed websocket server.

However, if I do a standalone build after that and create an .app with a game, the code above produces an error:

```
OSXPlayer(<hostname>)</i> NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
  at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri, System.Boolean useUriBase) [0x000db] in <f044fe2c9e7e4b8e91984b41f0cf0b04>:0
```

Why does that happen? How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue in 2017.1.0f3 when building for iOS. I noticed that it doesn't actually matter what the prefix is, as it happens with http as well. This seems to be the same too: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89614/webrequest-create-uri-uri-throws-system-notsupportedexception-the-uri-prefix-is-not-recognized

Comment: Same problem, 2017.1.0f3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fixed in future release, 2017.3.0b1.

Reproduced with: 2017.1.0p2, 2017.2.0b5, 2017.3.0a2

Backported to 2017.1.1p2, 2017.2.0b11 
Fixed in: 2017.3.0b1

---

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/dot-net-4-dot-6-ios-build-throws-notsupportedexception-when-creating-a-webrequest-via-system-dot-net-dot-webrequest-dot-create